# Make sure JDBC/JPA won't modify the DB?

Tags: sql-server, jpa, jdbc, privileges

I have a MS SQL Server with a DB that is constantly updated.
I have the credentials to access it with admin privileges.

And I'm making a Java EE webapp to display (hence, only display) its data.
But I have to make sure that, under *any* consequences,
My webapp doesn't modify the DB.

And no, the owners of the DB don't want to make an unprivileged user for the webapp.
Any ideas? I'm using JDBC + JPA.

Comment: Mark all you database transactions as read-only? What are you using for transaction management?

Comment: I'm using EclipseLink 2.0, but I'm flexible.

Comment: I want to make sure my webapplication won't modify the DB through the JDBC connection, even if I accidentally program one of the methods to do so.

Comment: Admin privileges but no read-only user? ... Why?

Comment: Because the owners of the DB don't know how to these things correctly. Sorry, but they won't let me have a read-only user. :'(

Comment: O....k. Would they allow you to create views? Edit: Doesn't help, if you want to prevent accidents.

Comment: Teach the owners of the DB how to create a read-only user. Link your explanation to a section of the official SQL Server documentation. Obscurantism or ignorance is never the best solution.

Comment: @JBNizet +1 yes, I have telled 'em a million times, but they _don't want to change_. They are a full company and I'm a 15-aged student. So I don't have the authority to force them.

Comment: @his Exactly, I what I want is to prevent accidents.

Comment: I think JPA is an over kill if all you want to do is read only transactions. I think straight SQL would give better performance and control in this case (no insert or update queries means no updates to db). You can look at Spring JdbcTemplate or Ibatis or just write straight sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In EclipseLink you could mark all your objects as `@ReadOnly`, so they won't be written.
2. You could also register an event listener to throw an error on persist, update or remove.